# Using Scrollbar plugin with DIVs having 100% height

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I tried to use the [jQuery Scrollbar plugin](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/) with my 3-column-layout (**Update:** Switched to **[slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) plugin** now). The 3 columns shall use 100% browser height. The idea is that the scrollbars only appear when hovering the corresponding column.

With my layout the scrollbar is not working fine. I already call the function each time the window is resized (what I initially tried to avoid because its - from my point of view - a hack):

```
$(window).resize(function()
```

**Here  is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/deb_ugger/n7y31wzb/5/)**.

The code to initialize the scrollbar is in line 226 (before I pasted the jquery.slimscroll.js).

```js
function setFrameSizes() {
  console.log("Set scrollbar");
  $('.inner').slimScroll({
    height: $(window).height() - 46
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setFrameSizes();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  setFrameSizes();
});
```

Comment: I would recommend [slim scroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated my fiddle to use slim scroll. Now at least the scroll bars are shown - but still not ok. Might the CSS of my layout cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every div has the same height:

```
var myHeight = $('.myDiv').height();
$(".myDiv").slimscroll({
    wheelStep: 20,
    color: '#fff',
    height: myHeight
});
```

If that's not the case then you could maybe try referencing to the each div by ID, or something like this:

```
$(".myDiv").each(function(){
     var myHeight = $(this).height();
     $(this).slimscroll({
        wheelStep: 20,
        color: '#fff',
        height: myHeight
      });

});
```

Comment: Using a fix height works, but not having an "auto" height. The height of the 3 columns depend on the height of the browser window.

Comment: @stephan please edit your question, maybe it can be useful to someone someday.

Comment: I tried to avoid checking browser window height. But it seems there is no other way round. I now call the slimscroll function on $(window).resize(function(), but its not setting the height properly.